# Ложные срабатывания wait() условной переменной

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, condition-variable

Столкнулся с утверждением, что в потоковых API (причем не только в C++) бывают ситуации, когда при вызове функции `wait()` для условной переменной может произойти активация кода, ожидающего данную переменную условия, даже если событие не произошло (т.е. не было уведомления условной переменной).

Вопросы:

1. Как часто такое происходит?
2. С чем связано такое поведение `wait()`?
3. Можно проверять выполнение условие непосредственно из ожидающего кода после потенциально ложного срабатывания `wait()` или же использовать булев флаг на основе `std::atomic` (можно и просто переменную типа `bool`). Такой подход вызывает удивление, поскольку явно предполагает неопределенное поведение `wait()`. Как выйти из этой ситуации?

Comment: Тоже кстати удивило это. Получается, что старый добрый способ с использованием Event и WaitForMultipleObjects/WaitForSingleObjects надежнее. Или я что-то не понимаю

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для этой ситуации существует англоязычный термин: [Spurious wakeup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup).

Ответы:

1. Вопрос не имеет смысла, т.к. прямого ответа на него нет: никто такой статистики не ведёт. Но раз такое возможно, значит нужно писать код в том ключе, что такая ситуация может происходить хоть каждый день.
2. Некое подобие объяснения можно найти на англоязычном SO: [Why does pthread_cond_wait have spurious wakeups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594591/why-does-pthread-cond-wait-have-spurious-wakeups), [Does C# Monitor.Wait() suffer from spurious wakeups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461913/does-c-sharp-monitor-wait-suffer-from-spurious-wakeups/1461956#1461956).
3. Не нужно никаких булевых переменных. Вы же ждёте не в вакууме, а какого-то события, будь то наполнение очереди или же выставление флага — просто нужно дополнительно удостовериться, что событие наступило. Нельзя доверять одному выходу из `wait`.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте wait с предикатом:

```
cv.wait(lock, [&]{ return ...; }
```

Это эквивалентно

```
while (!predicate()) {
  wait(lock);
}
```

Ложные пробуждения это норма, они задокументированы в API windows и linux.
В windows могут происходить при использовании механизма [APC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954(v=vs.85).aspx).